# libGDX collision with texture and ShapeRenderer

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having a bit of a problem with my collision. I have a dog object with two circles, one for his head, the other for his fat body, and a circle that represent a ball texture that hit\collides with the dog's circles (the first one it touches).
Now, all circles are a bit bigger than the texture the represent them. 
When I draw them with the SpriteBatch it seem like the textures move inside each other before the collision affect happen, but when I draw the only the circles with ShapeRenderer, the collision affect take place the moment the circles hit\collide.
Why with the different between the SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer?

EDIT MY CODE:
Dog's circles:

```
    boundingCircleHead.set(position.x + 9.5f, position.y + 6, 6.5f); 
    boundingCircleBody.set(position.x + 9.5f, position.y + 16, 6.5f);
```

Ball's circle:

```
    ball.x = MathUtils.random(0, 121);
    ball.y = -13;
    ball.radius = 11f;
```

Draw ball:

```
batcher.draw(BALL, ball.x, ball.y, 17, 19);
shapeRenderer.circle(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius);
```

Draw dog:

```
batcher.draw(dogAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), dog.getX(), dog.getY(), dog.getWidth(), dog.getHeight());

shapeRenderer.circle(dog.getBoundingCircleHead().x, dog.getBoundingCircleHead().y, dog.getBoundingCircleHead().radius);
shapeRenderer.circle(dog.getBoundingCircleBody().x, dog.getBoundingCircleBody().y, dog.getBoundingCircleBody().radius);
```

Collision:

```
            if (Intersector.overlaps(ball, dog.getBoundingCircleHead()) || Intersector.overlaps(ball, dog.getBoundingCircleBody())) {
                gameOver();
            }
```

Comment: You need to show us the most important code parts: The collision detection (which seems to work) and the drawing with S`hapeRenderer` and `SpriteBatch`. I guess you just `draw` the `Sprite` with a wrong position/size, while you are using the rigth size with `ShapeRenderer`

Comment: OK, edit and added my code.

Comment: First of all: As much as i remember you should never have 2 `Renderer`s active at once. So `draw` with `batcher` first, call `batcher.end()`, and `draw()` with `shapeRenderer`. The problem could be, that the position you give the `ShapeRenderer#circle()` is the circles center (not sure), while `SpriteBatch`s `draw()` takes the lower, left corner as position.

Comment: Deleted my previews comment since I tried some things and thanks to your explanation of how SB and SR draw, I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: So was it, that the `ShapeRenderer#circle` uses the centerpoint, while `SpriteBatch` uses the left lower corner?

Comment: I thinks the ShapeRenderer draw in the top left corner, because when I draw them both in the render the circle was in the top left corner of the texture.

Comment: Ah okay. Can you add it as an answer then?